# Reference to a non-exported function in 'environment' 'environment' contains the error at environments/environment.ts(29,10)

Tags: angular

ERROR in app/app.module.ts(130,63): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Reference to a non-exported function in 'environment'
    'environment' contains the error at environments/environment.ts(29,10).

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: I am having the same problem with angular 7.1.2 when I do a prod build any help on this problem?